# Non-MVC created stores wont instantiate until viewport is loaded in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have some code which creates stores on the fly from an ajax request to the server (which sends a json store).Everything works fine meaning when I check the DOM,the stores are already there. But When I insert this code in my app.js to create an instance of Countries store:

```
new MA.store.Countries();
```

I get  following error:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'MA.store.Countries' is not a constructor
```

After the viewport is loaded completely, I run the same code in firebug and magically I can see the store is created and accessible.
While googling on the net i found a similar question in [sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?139761-Use-widget-or-call-store-in-the-viewport-problem) but no answers are provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and thinking i found a workaround and probably a solution.Firstly, i let my viewport created without grids that need ajax JSON stores,then i Ext.getCmp() my vieport`s tabpanel and add() and doLayout() the grids inside my viewport.ajax's callback function so grids are only added when JSON is returned and store is created.

To see how i implemented this solution in action,you may check [MedAlyser`s source](https://www.assembla.com/code/medalyser/subversion/nodes/trunk/code/public/app.js)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```js
myStore = Ext.create('MA.store.Countries', options);
```

This will handle all class loading and instancing of your store. See [Ext API on Ext.create()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-create) for more Details.

Comment: You need to give more information about how you define/load stores in the working example and the one throwing the error. An code example would be nice :-)

Comment: viewall.js is accessible on our assembla svn[link](https://www.assembla.com/code/medalyser/subversion/nodes/trunk/code/public/app/view/patient/ViewAll.js).Thanks for having a look.As musch as i could understand,store is AFTER viewport and grid is rendered and because the store for some reason is not created,it throws an exception saying that store is undefined.my code is working in firefox with no errors but i get no constructor errors in IE and opera.

Comment: IE is know to be more strict with JavaScript, if your code works in Firefox but not IE, clean it up.